# How to find/replace html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm looking for a javascript solution to find all jQuery scripts on a html page and replace the code with the latest version of jQuery.

Original line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Replace with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: replace it? can't you modify the code instead of changing the jQuery library with jQuery?

Comment: Beware, many things changed since 1.3. It may break, those versions aren't fully compatible

Comment: I understand how simple the solution can be. Unfortunately this isn't possible. I really looking for the javascript solution.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just point to the latest library?

Comment: I don't think that jquery.com is a CDN... (or at least effective in being one)

Comment: the problem itself is dangerous anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('script[src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"]'),
script;
for(var i=0, len = all.length; i < len; i++){
    script = all[i].cloneNode(false);
    script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js";
    document.body.removeChild(all[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

That works for me. You can see it in [this demo](http://pastehtml.com/view/bfvjbabau.html), but you'll have to type the command `$.fn.jquery` in the console to see that the version has actually changed.

Comment: You can demonstrate that the source has changed all you want, but it won't actually run the loaded script.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Most of the examples people are writing DON'T WORK!</strike> *(Examples have been removed.)* `jQuery().jquery` returns the jQuery version:

```
$("script[src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js']")
    .attr("src","http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js");
console.log(jQuery().jquery);
```

This writes `1.3.2` to the console. Just changing the src of a script doesn't make the new script actually run! Even if you give the new script chance to load with a `setTimeout` or load event, it still won't change the version.

You could load the script as an AJAX query and `eval` it.

```
jQuery.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js");
```

But even that might not produce the result you expect. Any reference to `jQuery` or `$` further down the page will have already pointed to the old jQuery object (version 1.3.2), not the new one. So to use 1.7.2, you'd then have to `eval` all your scripts only after getting and `eval`ing the new script. So you're gonna have to find another way I'm afraid.

**Edit:** I suppose you could do this:

```
jQuery.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js", function () {
    // Only after jQuery has run
    jQuery.getScript('my-script-which-depends-on-1.7.js');
});
```

but it's a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score -1):

Open up the source of your project in an editor like notepad++ or any other advanced source code editor. Search for the text "1.3.2/jquery.min.js" in all available source files (by recursively searching through the root of your project). Check if all occurrences of the string need to be replaced and then use the find/replace tool to change it to the latest version.

Comment: He wants to do this using JavaScript. (Odd, but well, that's what he asked for.)

Comment: I understand how simple the solution can be. Unfortunately this isn't possible. I really looking for the javascript solution.