# Find a particular keywords in HTML tags and replace using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i need to do is to find a particular strings inside my HTML and if found i will replace it with nothing.

Exp :

HTML:

```
<img src=`javascript:alert("hello ,world!")`>
```

What i need to do is to find the occurrence of some keywords like javascript , alert , etc and if found inside HTML tags like the one above i need to replace it with empty string.

i know jquery has some useful functions like

> .find() , .replace() and :contains

but really i could not figure out how to do it because i am not that good in javascript.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is that done on the client side, instead of on the server (backend), using PHP for example? What you want to do, is parsing the HTML-content via JS…

Comment: Hope you need all these to happen in your development phase and not at the run time !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342298/how-to-find-replace-html-with-javascript

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? As others have mentioned it should likely be done on the server side as doing this on client-side seems really messy. Hell, doing it on server side even seems a bit messy to me. Why do you have this code in there if you don't want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing isn't even something that really needs jQuery to be done easily. Here's an example in pure JavaScript.

HTML

```
<a id="someLink" src="javascript:alert('hello world!')">LINK THAT DOES STUFF</a>
//how an image tag can have a JS src is beyond me.
```

Now if I wanted to look for keywords like '*javascript*' in say the *src* attribute. I would first get the DOM element like so:

```
var domObject=document.getElementByID('someLink') 
/*$('someLink') is jQuery equivalent*/
```

Now to get what's in said attribute I'd use `domObject.getAttribute('src')` 
this would return "javascript:alert('hello world!')"

Finally I would have a function that brings everything together and simply detects what I'm looking for and empties it.

```
    function getRidofJavascriptInSrc(object){
       a=object.getAttribute('src');
       if(/javascript/i.test(a)) //this is REGEX, it will look for the keyword JavaScript and run statement if true
       {object.setAttribute('src')=""}
    } 
   getRidofJavascriptInSrc($('someLink'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question if you already know what attributes you want to check for, so I will give two solutions- depending whether you know already or not.
If you know the attribute where you want to search for the keywords, try this:

```
var attribVal = $("img").attr("src");
if (attribVal.match(/(javascript)|(alert)/i)
{
    $("img").attr("src", "");
}
```

If you don't know the attribute names, then store the html in a variable and compare in the value of the variable. Assuming the following div to be the parent for the img tag:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <img src=`javascript:alert("hello ,world!")` id='myImg'>
</div>
```

Do the following:

```
 var myVar = $("#myDiv").html();
 if (attribVal.match(/(javascript)|(alert)/i)
 {
    $("img#myImg").attr("src", "");
 }
```